# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host...[internal function]

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a PHP Client.

The Server WSDL is https://34.200.105.231/VENTAS_SOAP/VentaService.svc?wsdl

The webservices generated by the session work without any problems

```
$params = array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2);
$ws     = new SoapClient(
    'https://34.200.105.231/VENTAS_SOAP/VentaService.svc?wsdl',
    $params
);

$parametros = array(    'sesion'    =>  array(
                            'IDSesion'  => "44444",
                            'IDCliente' => "rick", 
                            'IDEmpresa' => "rick",
                            'IDUsuario' => "user",
                            'Token' => '',
                        ),'codigo'          => 'ac',
                        'descripcion'       => '',
                        'cantidadRegistros' => '1',
                        'pagina'            => '0'
);

print_r(print_r($ws->__soapCall("ConsultaArticulosServicios",$parametros)));
```

Not work, Response:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: 
[HTTP] Could not connect to host in /home/admin/web/xxxxxxxx/public_html/nusoapfontana/metodos/index3.php:41 
Stack trace: 
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://df-0e7d...', 'VentaServicio/V...', 2, 0) 
#1 /home/admin/web/xxxxxxxx/public_html/nusoapfontana/metodos/index3.php(41): SoapClient->__soapCall('ConsultaArticul...', Array) 
#2 {main} thrown in /home/admin/web/xxxxxxxx/public_html/nusoapfontana/metodos/index3.php on line 41
```

If I can access the Login function found here:
[Http://34.200.105.231/SID/Service.svc?wsdl](http://34.200.105.231/SID/Service.svc?wsdl)

Here I generate the data for the session.

Comment: try http no s, looks like the cert is invlaid

Comment: Yes, i try http, and the error is equal.  Is more, I have modified my file host in the server to ignore de SSL.